# How do I set environment variables in Google Colab?

Tags: python, environment-variables, google-colaboratory

On my local computer, I can simply go into "System Properties -> Environment Variables" and add a new variable with its value in user variables.

Then, I can retrieve this value by using this in Python:

```
import os
os.environ["VAR_NAME"]
```

However, I just recently started using Google Colab, and it seems it's not able to detect the environment variable, as it gives me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-28128554cf91> in <module>()
      1 import os
----> 2 os.environ["REDDIT_NAME"]

/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    679         except KeyError:
    680             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 681             raise KeyError(key) from None
    682         return self.decodevalue(value)
    683 

KeyError: 'REDDIT_NAME'
```

How should I go about so that Google Colab can detect my user environment variables? Is there a specific path I need to modify?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Google Colab now supports adding keys and secrets on the notebook itself

Source: https://twitter.com/GoogleColab/status/1719798406195867814

> Configure your code by storing environment variables, file paths, or keys. Values stored here are private, visible only to you and the notebooks that you select.
>
> Secret name cannot contain spaces.

Steps:

1. Navigate to the "Secrets" pane from the left navigation bar
2. Add the secret name and value you want to manage
3. Turn on the toggle of "Notebook access"
4. Access your secret keys in Python via:

```
from google.colab import userdata
userdata.get('secretName')
```

If you need the secret to be set as an environment variable, then:

`%env KAGGLE_USERNAME=abcdefgh`

If the value is in a variable you can also use

`%env KAGGLE_USERNAME=$username`

Answer (score 5):

Like this

```
import os
os.environ['REDDIT_NAME'] = 'something'
print(os.getenv('REDDIT_NAME'))
```

Or using `dotenv` lib. Keep environment in a file:

```
  import dotenv
  dotenv.load_dotenv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), './.env'))
```

in .env file:
`REDDIT_NAME = something`

and ignore .env file when push to git

Comment: I don't want the actual value to be in the code since I'll be pushing this to a public GitHub. If I do `os.environ['REDDIT_NAME'] = 'something'`, won't that expose the value of `'something'`?

Comment: you can using dotenv lib. And push your value to an file and ignore it when push to git.
`import dotenv
dotenv.load_dotenv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), './.env'))`
in .env file: REDDIT_NAME = something

Answer (score 3):

Install the following packages.

```py
!pip install --quiet openai python-dotenv
```

Create a `.env` file like this:

```bash
/content# cat .env
OPENAI_API_KEY="sk-*"
OPENAI_ORGANIZATION="org-*"
/content#
```

In Colab, it can be read as an environment variable in the following cell.

```py
import dotenv
dotenv.load_dotenv('./.env')
```

You can hide it as an environment variable and assign it to the variable.

```py
import os
import openai
openai.api_key = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]
```